# How to find the gradient of $x+y-z-\ln z=0$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative, implicit-differentiation

> I need to find the directional derivative of $x+y-z=\ln z$ in the point $(1,0,1)$ in the direction which is formed at the angle of $\arctan({4 \over 3})$ with the positive values of $x$ axis.

The gradient $\nabla f=\langle f_x, f_y,f_z\rangle=\langle z_x, z_y,z_z\rangle$.

I got the partial derivative for $z_x=z_y=\frac{z}{z+1}$ but I don't understand how to differentiate the given function implicitly for $z$.

Any suggestions would be highly welcome.

Comment: You want to define $f = x + y - z - \ln z \implies \nabla f = (1, 1, -1 - 1/z)$

Comment: @Mattos can you please explain how you got there? I guess my calculation is not correct

Comment: You haven't specified a vector direction to go in. So either you only need to calculate $\nabla f$ or you haven't provided all the information in the question.

Comment: @Mattos I added more details. I thought we can calculate the directional derivative by $||\nabla f||\cdot \cos \theta$. But first I need $||\nabla f||$

Comment: @Mattos I actually think I got confused with finding the gradient in 4 dimensions, so in our case $\nabla f=\langle f_x, f_y \rangle$ right?

Comment: @Mattos my main concern is that I calculated the $f_x=f_y=\frac{z}{z+1}$ so when we plug in the given $z$ value I get $\nabla f=\langle {1\over 2}, {1 \over 2} \rangle$

Comment: You have it: $\nabla f·\langle 3,4\rangle$

Comment: @RafaBudría how did you get $\langle 3,4 \rangle$?

Comment: Transform it into polars: $3=r\cos\theta$ and $4=r\sin\theta$, for some $r$ but the angle is $\theta=\arctan(4/3)$. ($\theta$ is the polar angle, so is, the angle of the vector with the $x$ axis).

Comment: I am very sorry, we have to use an unitary vector in the desired direction, so is $\langle 3/5,4/5 \rangle$. Now,$D_{\langle 3/5,4/5 \rangle}f=\nabla f·\langle 3/5,4/5\rangle$